# Grid Default Grouping after regrouping

Tags: extjs4

I have a Grid with Grouping feature. I have set the "groupField" config to the column on which I want grouping. So when the page get load , Grid shows the grouped columns.and it is working fine.

for my requirement, I have not added the column [on which I am doing grouping] to the Grid. So the Grid doesn't show the Grouped column.

so the scenario is like.

if eg.

```
Grid with 5 column [Name, Email,Status,address,city]
currently displayed column= 4 [Name,Email,address,city]
Grouped column=  1 [status]
```

Now My Query is, out 4 [currently displayed ] column if, I changed the grouping to "city", [remember, on page load we have grouped Grid data, since I have set "groupField=status"  in store] how will I go back for the default grouping [i.e. Grouping on status column]?

Note: The column "status" is not displayed to Grid, there is no header option from which I can change the Grouping.

Hope I am able to explain well here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create button which will turn on grouping by status like in [Ext JS example](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/examples/grid/groupgrid.html) (there is only clearing, but you can do grouping as well).

Another possibility is to create handler on `beforeload` event in store, and check if there is any grouping turned on - if not turn on grouping by `status`.  Then you can't turn off grouping.